# Appending Rasterlayer as SUBDATASET into existing geopackage using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, gdal, geopackage, append

I struggle with appending a RASTER Subdataset to an existing Geopackage using Python code.
Meanwhile I can save one Raster to a new Geopackage but that's not my plan.

```
from qgis import processing
translate_params = { 'INPUT' : 'GPKG:C:/Users/MF/Desktop/testPackage.gpkg:onemoreraster',
'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/MF/Desktop/testPackage4.gpkg'
}
processing.run("gdal:translate",translate_params)
```

that code actually allows me to create a new Geopackage containing the  layer 'onemoreraster'.
To my reseach it needs some CreationOptions called APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES and RASTER_TABLE=newTablename, but I have no idea how to place it  into the dictionary .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like the code snippet below. In the parameters dictionary, `'INPUT':` should be the path to a raster (.tif, .gpkg etc) which you want to add as a raster table to a geopackage.

`'OUTPUT':` should be the path to your existing geopackage to which the table will be appended.

I used dummy file names in the paths so please change accordingly.

The additional creation options are added inside a string value for the `'EXTRA':` key, including the `-co` switch for each option.

```py
params = {'INPUT':'C:/Users/MF/Desktop/inputRaster.gpkg',#raster to add to geopackage
        'TARGET_CRS':None,
        'NODATA':None,
        'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,
        'OPTIONS':'',
        'EXTRA':'-co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=onemoreraster',#create options
        'DATA_TYPE':0,
        'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/MF/Desktop/existingPackage.gpkg'}#existing geopackage to append to

processing.run("gdal:translate", params)
```

Here is what it would look like using a for loop to add all selected raster layers in the layer tree to an existing geopackage, taking each layer's name in the layers panel and using it in the algorithm create options as the table name in the destination geopackage.

```py
selected_rasters = iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers()

for rl in selected_rasters:
    
    if not rl.type() == QgsMapLayerType.RasterLayer:
        continue

    params = {'INPUT':rl.source(),#retrieve source path from loop variable
            'TARGET_CRS':None,
            'NODATA':None,
            'COPY_SUBDATASETS':False,
            'OPTIONS':'',
            'EXTRA':f'-co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE={rl.name()}',#retrieve name from loop variable
            'DATA_TYPE':0,
            'OUTPUT':'C:/Users/Path/To/test.gpkg'}#existing geopackage to append to

    processing.run("gdal:translate", params)
```

Comment: Perfect, that works me! Thanks Ben.

Comment: @Mathias Friedrich, no problem! You are very welcome, glad it worked :-)

Comment: Hi @Mathias Friedrich, what if I need to export selected multiple rasters to a gkpg, and the out put table name need to be the name on the layer tree. What should I do? Because this current code will only export one raster with the name 'onemoreraster'. I have called the selectedLayers as ras, and I have put the params in a for loop.  How should I modify that 'EXTRA' line?

Comment: @LEI, note that you 'atted' the question asker not the answerer. I have edited my answer to show you an example of how to do this.

Comment: @BenW Hi, oh no! I am so sorry and thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @LEI, no problem  I hope it worked.

Comment: Hi@BenW, I just tried the code, it executed with no error, but it didn't add those rasters into my Gpkg. Do you know what might be the reason? Sorry to bother you again. It did work with you original code, so I guess still the 'EXTRA'line

Comment: Hi @BenW, no worries, I changed it to .format(rl.name()). and it works now

Comment: @LEI, hmm, strange. It should work with f-string formatting (you did add the `f` in front of the string, didn't you?). It certainly worked for me when I tested it. Anyway, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @BenW, Hi, yes, I did use the F string. it is weird that not working on my end. Thank you anyway. I wouldn't be able to make up the whole line without your help. :)

Comment: @LEI, no problem- you're welcome.